# What is a good collection of alcohol to keep around for someone who doesn't drink?

Tags: recommendations

I don't drink alcohol at all, but I'd like to keep some kind of selection around to offer to guests who do. I'm not looking to fully stock a bar, but at least a few different options that can accommodate a variety of tastes and also not require prompt consumption.

Comment: I voted to close. This is far too broad and also subjective. There are a huge number of possible answers, and some of them may be good for some people, not for others.

Comment: Fair enough. I can understand the vagueness although I also don't know how to make my question more specific.

Comment: We've had questions pop up about specific types of alcohol for people who don't drink, for instance - good starter beers. Whereas this question just seems to have way too many variables and possible answers. In short, you'd probably need to know your likely guests, and what their tastes were.

Answer (score 2):

The kinds of alcohol you'd want can differ depending on the occasion or type of hosting you'll be doing. If a friend helps you move a couch, for example, it would not be unexpected to offer them a beer afterward as a thank you.

Wine can be offered but is probably more acceptable in the evenings or with a specific meal. One bottle of white and one of red should be sufficient. Chardonnay is probably a safe bet for white wine and a Merlot or Cabernet Sauvignon for red, but your guests' individual tastes can obviously differ.

Liquor like vodka or whiskey can be used to make a variety of cocktails (again, during or after dinner are commonplace) and for guests who want to party these can easily be used for shots as well. Many people have preferences towards specific brands, but if you buy a $20-30 bottle you won't have many guests turn it down just over the name.

Comment: It's probably worth saying something about how long each of these drinks can be kept.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the liquor can be stored indefinitely. Most beers will last a minimum of 6 months if stored in a cool place, and much longer if kept refrigerated (obviously opened beers would need to be discarded if not consumed). Wine can also be kept for months/ years, but once opened probably should be finished or disposed of within a week.